# Problems with replacing newline

Tags: powershell

Iam trying to replace following string with PowerShell:

```
...
("
Intel(R) Network Connections 14.2.100.0
","
14.2.100.0
")
...
```

The code that I use is:

```
Get-Content $logfilepath | 
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '`r`n`r`n', 'xx'} | 
Set-Content $logfilepath_new
```

But I have no success, can someone say me, where the error is?

Answer (score 3):

First, you are using single quotes in the replace string -

```
'`r`n`r`n'
```

that means they are treated verbatim and not as newline characters, so you have to use -

```
"`r`n`r`n"
```

To replace, read the file as string and use the `Replace()` method

```
$content=[string] $template= [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt")
$content.Replace("`r`n`r`n","xx")
```

Answer (score 2):

Get-content returns an array of lines, so CRLF is essentially your delimiter.  Two CRLF sequences back to back would be interpreted as the end of the currrent line, followed by a null line, so no line (object) should contain '`r`n`r`n'.  A multi-line regex replace would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

as alternate method using PS cmdlets:

```
Get-Content $logfilepath | 
    Foreach-Object -Begin { $content="" } -Process { $content += $_ ; $content += "xx" } -End { $content } | 
    Set-Content $logfilepath_new
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to replace `somestring` with newline:

```
$nl = [System.Environment]::NewLine
$content = $content.Replace( somestring, $nl )
```