# Fart.exe replace two carriage returns in a row

Tags: csv, batch-file, replace, cmd, fart

I have csv file where I'm trying to replace two carriage returns in a row with a single carriage return using Fart.exe. First off, is this possible? If so, the text within the CSV is laid out like the below where "CRLF" is an actual carriage return.

```
,CRLF
CRLF
```

But I want it to be just this without the extra carriage return on the second line:

```
,CRLF
```

I thought I could just do the below but it won't work:

```
CALL "C:\tmp\fart.exe" -C "C:\tmp\myfile.csv" ,\r\n\r\n ,\r\n
```

I need to know what to change **,\r\n\r\n** to in order to make this work. Any ideas how I could make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: [Not using FART](https://superuser.com/a/1127064)!

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925730/problems-with-replacing-newline) using powershell.

Comment: Seems like you are just talking about removing an empty line.

Answer (score 2):

As Squashman has suggested, you are simply trying to remove empty lines.

There is no need for a 3rd party tool to do this. You can simply use FINDSTR to discard empty lines:

```
findstr /v "^$" myFile.txt >myFile.txt.new
move /y myFile.txt.new *. >nul
```

However, this will only work if all the lines end with CRLF. If you have a unix formatted file that ends each line with LF, then it will not work.

A more robust option would be to use [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression command line text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044).

```
jrepl "^$" "" /r 0 /f myFile.txt /o -
```

Be sure to use CALL JREPL if you put the command within a batch script.

FART processes one line at a time, and the CRLF is not considered to be part of the line. So you can't use a normal FART command to remove CRLF. If you really want to use FART, then you will need to use the -B binary mode. You also need to use -C to get support for the escape sequences.

I've never used FART, so I can't be sure - but I believe the following would work

```
call fart -B -C myFile.txt "\r\n\r\n" "\r\n"
```

If you have many consecutive empty lines, then you will need to run the FART command repeatedly until there are no more changes.